# FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory 's3

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, nexus, amazon-iam

I am trying to get Nexus data which is stored in my S3 bucket `mbop-devo` account. S3 bucket where nexus service is writing data is in `mbop-devo` account. Bucket policy is pasted below.

Now I want to get data into another S3 bucket in my own AWS account `korgak`. Inside `korgak` account I have assumed nexus role. When I am trying to SQL query, in output, it is returning my nexus data name. But when select query is running, its giving error:

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory 's3://mbop-na-preprod-nexus/mbopCustomerData/00242/2018-12-28T0041/PT1M/a403dc78-aded-46c9-b424-18344564438d.gz'

File is present in S3 bucket I am not sure where is the permission is missing

S3 bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "NexusSystemPermissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::255137427906:role/EmrEc2Instance"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mbop-na-preprod-nexus/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mbop-na-preprod-nexus"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "CrossAccountPermissions1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::255137427906:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mbop-na-preprod-nexus"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "CrossAccountPermissions2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::997380610533:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mbop-na-preprod-nexus"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "CrossAccountPermissions3",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::997380610533:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mbop-na-preprod-nexus/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "CrossAccountPermissions4",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::255137427906:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mbop-na-preprod-nexus/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If the object mentioned in the error message exists, then it is a permissions problem. Which is the ARN for the "nexus role" that you are using to access the bucket? Also, what are the permissions assigned to the "nexus role"? (Feel free to edit your question to add more detail, and also remove detail that is not relevant.)

Comment: NexusRole ARN - arn:aws:iam::997380610533:root
NexusRole has assumed role policy -
`
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1457993729000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::255137427906:role/NexusClient-mbop-metrics"
        }
    ]
}
`
arn:aws:iam::255137427906:role/NexusClient-mbop-metrics is the role given to us by Nexus to assume.

Comment: I have given AmazonS3FullAccess to nexus role

Comment: What happens if you try to access it via the AWS CLI? You can add the role to the AWS CLI configuration, then just try `aws s3 ls s3://mbop-na-preprod-nexus/mbopCustomerData/00242/2018-12-28T0041/PT1M/a403dc78-aded-46c9-b424-18344564438d.gz`

Comment: I have added below lines to aws/credentials file
    [mbop-us-access-preprod]
role_arn=arn:aws:iam::997380610533:role/NexusRole
source_profile=korgak
[mbop-nexus-profile]
role_arn=arn:aws:iam::255137427906:role/NexusClient-mbop-metrics
source_profile=mbop-us-access-preprod

Comment: aws --profile mbop-us-access-preprod returns file details on ls. But aws --profile mbop-nexus-profile says 'An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:sts::997380610533:assumed-role/NexusRole/botocore-session-1580195379 is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::255137427906:role/NexusClient-mbop-metrics'